# Document is not returned when searched using query parameter in solr

Tags: solr, solr8

I updated a document in solr using the below query and it was successful.The document has other fields like organization_name,place etc apart from what is shown in the api below.

```
curl  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8390/solr/collection/update?commit=true' -d '[{"id" : “12345”,”code” : {"set" : “500”}}]’
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "rf":1,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":11}}
```

Post update, when I tried to query solr with query parameter(q) as name, it does not return any document. At the same time, if I query using name as fq parameter, I see the document coming up fine.

This query doesnot work:-

```
http://localhost:8390/solr/collection/select?q=test&qf=content^0.1%20name_display_name^1.0&defType=edismax
```

But,this query works(with fq param),

```
http://localhost:8390/solr/collection/select?q=*%3A*&rows=1000&fq=ngram_info_organization_name:test
```

The field type of organization_name is string and its both indexed and stored.

This issue is seen only for the document that i updated. If I query for other documents which are not updated, i am able to see the results.

Please help to figure out why the document is not listed when I use the name with query parameter.

Comment: could you please share the exact query and what is the fields type applied on your field name?

Comment: Hi Abhijit..Yes, I have updated the queries.

Comment: did you tried::  q=ngram_info_organization_name:test&rows=1000&

Comment: also you need to check that in conf/solrconfig.xml Check for "df" parameter. You may need to change it to <str name="df">ngram_info_organization_name</str>

Comment: if you do the changes in solrconfig.xml then you can write query as q=test

Comment: But for all other documents, I see that q=orgname works. Only for the document i updated through curl is having this problem. So, I am not able to understand what went wrong when i did an update.

Comment: The documents which are updated through curl...please check if all the required fields are there or did they got removed during the update?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Yes, I checked. All required fields are present.i compared the fields of this document with other documents, there are no changes in the fields.

Comment: If you update a field, all non-copied fields in the schema needs to be set as stored; if they're not set as stored, they'll disappear after an update has been issued. Since your example includes different field names, it's not weird that they behave differently - and since you haven't included any examples of documents or your schema, it's hard for anyone else to say what the expected behavior should be. Include the document as returned by Solr before and after your update, and query _the same fields_ both times.

Comment: Eli Johnes Here is the link https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html what @MatsLindh is trying to tell you. The core functionality of atomically updating a document requires that all fields in your schema must be configured as stored (stored="true") or docValues (docValues="true") except for fields which are <copyField/> destinations, which must be configured as stored="false". Atomic updates are applied to the document represented by the existing stored field values.